# How can i use milliseconds (bigInt) value to use mysql partitioning on day?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning

I want to use mysql partitioning feature.

I have a column log_time in which i store milliseconds as bigint (assuming i cannot alter it).

I want 31 partitions, one for each day (calculated using log_time value).

What i tried :

```
alter table my_table partition by hash(day(from_unixtime(log_time/1000))) partitions 31;
```

I am getting : this partition function is not allowed.

Seems mysql only allows specific functions to be part of hash to be calculated for partitioning and it seems from_unixtime() is not one of them(?)

How can i achieve this partitioning on log_time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `BY HASH`, it won't work like you think.  In particular it will not speed up your processing.

Instead consider `BY RANGE`, and don't use a complex formula.  Instead of crunching milliseconds into a day, go the other way -- expand day constants into milliseconds.

Since you seem to be purging old data, `BY RANGE` is much better suited -- you can simply `DROP PARTITION` and `REORGANIZE` to get a new day's worth.  See this for more discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint